# Send data to Php server

Tags: php, iphone, asihttprequest

I want to send lat long after 30 sec....

for that i am using,

```
if (theDiff > 30.0f || myDate == nil){
        //do your webservices stuff here
        NSLog(@"Location get ===================");
        double lat =  newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        double longt = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;


        NSString *ids = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:CURRENT_USERID]];
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UPDATE_LATLONG]];

        [request setPostValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: lat] forKey:@"latitude"];
        [request setPostValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: longt] forKey:@"longitude"];
        [request setPostValue:ids forKey:@"userid"];
        [request startSynchronous];

        NSString *XMLResponseString = [request responseString];
        NSLog(@"XMLResponseString %@",XMLResponseString);
        [request release];

            NSLog(@"lat = %.6f",lat);
            NSLog(@"long = %.6f",longt);
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [prefs setObject:lastDate forKey:@"myDateKey"];
        [prefs synchronize];
    }
```

but is gives error...

```
2012-03-01 15:01:43.352 BiiMe[1638:207] +[NSString stringwithFormat:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x447fd8
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
(gdb)
```

what did i mistake?

Comment: Maybe you use 'stringwithFormat' not 'stringWithFormat'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try and use more CodeSense feature.

It's `stringWithFormat:` not `stringwithFormat:`

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Just search the string stringwithFormat in your project and replace it with stringWithFormat